# Hazard Rate Function mechanical device

Tags: probability

Suppose that the lifetime distribution of a mechanical device has hazard rate function $λ(t)=3.9⋅t^2$ for $t>0$. 
What is the probability that the device's lifetime will be between 1 and 2?

I tried $e^{-\int^2_13.9*t^2dt}=.000111666$, however this was wrong. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start from the definition, $\lambda(t)=\frac{f(t)}{1-F(t)}$ with $F(t)=\int_0^tf(t)dt$, then

$$1-F(t)=\frac{f(t)}{\lambda(t)}$$
 differentiating with respect to $t$

$$-f(t)=\frac{f'(t)}{\lambda(t)}-\frac{\lambda'(t)}{\lambda(t)^2}f(t)$$
$$0=\frac{f'(t)}{\lambda(t)}+(1-\frac{\lambda'(t)}{\lambda(t)^2})f(t)$$
$$\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}=\frac{\lambda'(t)}{\lambda(t)}-\lambda(t)$$
solving

$$ f(t)=c e^{\int(\frac{\lambda'(t)}{\lambda(t)}-\lambda(t))dt}$$

$$ f(t)=c e^{\int(\frac{2}{t}-3.9 t^2)dt}$$

Solving the integral and noting that $f$ is a probability distribution, so its area should be $1$, we get

$$f(t)=3.9 t^2 e^{-1.3 t^3}$$

What you are being asked is $F(2)-F(1)=0.2725$

This is how $f(t)$ looks like

[image]